# Change IE 11 Default alert

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

When i download something in ie it will show an alert "Do you want to open or save this file". in IE 8 the alert is coming in the middle of screen.  Like below

[image]

But in IE 11 the alert is coming at the bottom of screen. But i want it in center like IE 8. Is there any way to update the alert position.

[image]

Comment: Your users will be getting used to this functionality on **every site** they go to. Even if you could somehow change this, you'd frustrate users who just want to download a bunch of PDFs without doing anything with them.

Comment: yes..But its the requirement.

Comment: @ap.singh Sometimes you get dumb, impossible requirements that require you to say "sorry, can't do that".

Answer (score 4):

That cannot be changed. That is browser default.